# After Joomla 3.2 update recieve blank page on both front end and back end

Tags: joomla3.0

Just did the update. Have blank page on both front and back end. I've turned on maximum error reporting through configuration.

On front end receive error: 
Fatal error: Call to protected method JApplicationSite::route() from context '' in /u01/www/html/index.php on line 46

On back end receive error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PlgUserJoomla::setDefaultEncryption() in /u01/www/html/libraries/joomla/user/helper.php on line 335

Any ideas?

Comment: I have fixed the issue. The problem was occurring because I did not have read/write access required to the joomla core files/folders on our server.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very simple error occuring due to two problems:

1. Read/Write/Execute CHMOD settings as you said
2. If you have updated Joomla 3.x to 3.2 using FTP and uploaded only the core joomla directories, do not forget to upload new index.php file too. Because it is different from 3.x's index.php.